# Android Spinner Dialog Multi Column

Tags: android, spinner

Please help me.

**My spinner (Default Android):**
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-eEuaen-sRy4/VaVXkAJRKAI/AAAAAAAANYs/JWP-o9kxAjo/s505-Ic42/now.jpg

**I want (Custom):**
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-iQV1pNOMI6I/VaVXkCBoGDI/AAAAAAAANYs/s9eepi2IvLI/s505-Ic42/i-want.jpg

and my custom layout XML code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/boslukAz"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/boslukAz"
        android:background="@color/actionBarAcik"
        android:contentDescription="@string/uygulama_adi"
        android:id="@+id/simgeS"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/simgeB"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/simgeB"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So , where is the problem? You can add three 'ImageView' one after another.

Comment: I do it by created xml with 3 imageview
then in my adapter , I need to handle to put 3 imageview per row by myself

Comment: Not solved. I want RelativeLayout width %33...